# Can we combine two Django/python apps which connect to different databases into one integrated app

Tags: python, django

I have two standalone django apps that connect to different dbs. I want to make a parent app which routes the requests to one of the two child apps.

Is it possible and how can I achieve this? The parent app doesn't have to connect to any db, it should just route the requests to the child apps.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7):

This is possible. In Django think of apps as libraries that you can piece together and combine. So lets say you have the following:

1. App A connects to db A
2. App B connects to db B

You could just create one django project. Put both apps in your install apps INSTALLED_APPS. Check out the section on [Multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) in the django docs. It will explain how to configure your apps so that they will automatically route to the correct database. Finally you don't really need to create a third parent app. Then edit your project's urls.py and define a route for each app. You can also call app A from App B, and redirect requests from one to the other as you need.

**example urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

The example above will route two separate apps to two different urls. Both these apps [django.contrib.admindocs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/#module-django.contrib.admindocs) and [django.contrib.admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/) ship with Django. The example is taken from the [2nd part of the Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial02/#activate-the-admin-site).

Comment: Thank you Marwan Alsabbagh! Your answer is exactly what I am looking for. Could you describe some simple url config examples with this situation, please.

Comment: @gacon as requested I've updated the answer with an example urls.py. Glad to hear the answer was useful.