# Combining 2 different Django websites

Tags: python, django

I have 2 independent django websites that I want to merge into one another. To go about doing this can I just drag and drop the folders of one of the websites into the other and just change the root url.py and settings.py and it should work correct? Or is it more complicated that that?

Comment: You'll want to merge the databases as well

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can do this (also you will need to move the migrations of the models and run them in the other project as well). One of the advantages of working with Django, is the concept of "reusable apps." It's a huge win for you if you can develop your app as a module/package. This has implications in the architecture of your software design and in the decisions of what functionalities you want to add to your app.

Having all these, is going to benefit you in the long run. You can import your app into another Django project without too much hassle after that.

It's also part of the official documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/reusable-apps/

Hope this helps!

Comment: that doesn't really go into detail about merging apps just how to install a new one

Comment: I see. I found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730628/can-we-combine-two-django-python-apps-which-connect-to-different-databases-into 
My answer applies more when you are developing the apps from zero. Sorry that I got this wrong.

Comment: yea still not really helping :/